# Store persistent data in docker container directory

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I want to manually cache `node_modules` using Docker, something like this:

```
COPY . .  # copy everything (node_modules is gitignored though)
COPY package.json /tmp/test-deps
RUN (cd /tmp/test-deps && npm install --no-optional > /dev/null 2>&1)
RUN ln -s /tmp/test-deps/node_modules /root/cdt-tests/node_modules
```

this works, but it appears to me that `/tmp/test-deps/node_modules` is re-created each time the container is built.

How can I create a persistent directory so that I don't have to re-install node_modules each time?

Ridiculously difficult to find information on how to cache anything in any directory w/ Docker.

Comment: It's counterintuitive, because Docker handles caching its own way  - but this seems to work for me: https://blog.playmoweb.com/speed-up-your-builds-with-docker-cache-bfed14c051bf

Answer (score 1):

It's counterintuitive, because Docker handles caching its own way  - but this seems to work for me:

https://blog.playmoweb.com/speed-up-your-builds-with-docker-cache-bfed14c051bf

The bad way (Docker cannot do caching for you):

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node

WORKDIR /src
# Copy your code in the docker image
COPY . /src
# Install your project dependencies
RUN npm install
# Expose the port 3000
EXPOSE 3000
# Set the default command to run when a container starts
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

With a small change, we can give Docker the ability to cache things for us!

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:5.6.0
WORKDIR /src
# Expose the port 3000
EXPOSE 3000
# Set the default command to run when a container starts
CMD ["npm", "start"]
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /src
RUN npm install
# Copy your code in the docker image
COPY . /src
```